# Почему google play не подключаються, они начинают подключение и тут же завершаются, пытаюсь добавить рекорды

Tags: unity3d, google-play

Вот пример кода который использую

```
   private void Start()
    {
        Initialize();
           
    }
    void Initialize()
    {
        PlayGamesClientConfiguration config = new PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder()
            .RequestServerAuthCode(false).
            Build();
        PlayGamesPlatform.InitializeInstance(config);
        PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();
    }
```

Comment: добавьте пожалуйста больше информации, не очень понятно где именно у вас возникла проблема

Comment: проблема возникает именно при подключении google игры (при старте игры) идет загрузка и она завершаеться